# ocaml in function type how to use match with?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, ocaml

I need to solve this. Write a function (type 'a listl = Empty | Cons of 'a listl * 'a) list.
I have never used match with without list.
It is very confusing to use match with as an integer.

```
type 'a listl = Empty | Cons of 'a listl * 'a    

var: int -> (int -> 'a) ->'a listl

tabu 5 (fun x -> x^x) => [0;1;9;16;25]
```

Such results must come out.

```
type 'a listl = Empty | Cons of 'a listl * 'a    

let rec tabu n f =
match n with
| 0 -> 
| n -> if n > 0 then f n :: (tabu (n-1) f) else Empty
;;
```

In match with, how to use "0,n" instead of "Empty,Cons"?
Is there any good idea?

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem more clearly. If you try to solve a problem before understanding it, you're likely to end up with a solution to a different problem altogether. Which might be fun in itself, but probably not productive. Why do you think you need the match there at all?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to match values of type `int`. If you want to distinguish whether your parameter `n` has the value `0` or some other value, you can do it like so:

```
match n with
| 0 -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

where the underscore is an anonymous wildcard pattern that matches any value. (But in this `match` it will not match `0` because the first pattern takes precedence.) In this case you could achieve the same thing with an `if` like so:

```
if n=0
then ...
else ...
```

If you want to compare `n` with something that is not a constant, say `m`, then you cannot do just

```
match n with
| m -> ...
```

because that does not use `m` as its original binding. Instead it treats `m` as a non-anonymous wildcard pattern and introduces a new binding for `m` with the value of `n` in the expression following the pattern. So you have to do

```
if n=m
then ...
else ...
```

or use a `when` clause like so:

```
match n with
| _ when n=m ->
```